# How to get post id using add_my_endpoint?

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating AMP pages on my own, without a plugin, and I have one problem that I can't solve.

```
function h34_endpoints_add_endpoint_pinup()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('amp', EP_ALL);
}

add_action('init', 'h34_endpoints_add_endpoint_pinup');


add_filter('template_include', 'amp_page_template_pinup', 2);

function amp_page_template_pinup($template)
{
    if (get_query_var('amp', false) !== false) {
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'amp-template.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Now in the amp-template.php file ш need to get the post data (if it is a post) but where and how to get the post ID?

`global $post;` shows nothing

`get_the_ID()` - doesn't output anything either.

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: My initial thinking would be to pass it as a url parameter. eg: `amp-template.php?p=22`. You would then create a loop within your `amp-template.php` file and use [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) to retrieve it. On a personal note, i'm interested in your whole approach to implementing amp page if you have an open github I would love to take a look.

Comment: no, I want no additional parameters, I want it to be just /amp/

I would share the code, but this is a job for the client, and I can’t do it, when I figure out this task, I will definitely share the working code